# my custom admin .phtml file not showing?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I created adminhtml controller under practice->test->controllers->adminhtml->indexController.php it's working fine. But I created one menu in back-end and it's showing when I click on menu i created action to redirect my custom afficher.phtml, it's not redirecting given 401 error.

can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

my code is

practice->test->controllers->adminhtml->indexController.php

```
<?php

class Practice_Test_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        //echo 'admin test';
    }
}
```

practice->test->etc->config.xml

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Practice_Test_Adminhtml</module>
                    <frontName>practiceadmin</frontName>
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <test>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <menu>
            <test translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                <title>My Plugin</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <set_time>
                        <title>Address Book</title>
                        <action>practiceadmin/adminhtml_index</action>
                    </set_time>
                </children>
            </test>
        </menu>
    </adminhtml>
```

adminhtml->default->Practice->layout->test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <test_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="template1" type="test/template" template="test/afficher.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </test_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

adminhtml->default->Practice->test->afficher.phtml

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>"  />

<Div>
    Admin Html
</Div>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your indexAction() , you have not called any block and phtml file to show. Write you function like this

```
public function indexAction()
{
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->_title($this->__("Operations"));
       $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/folder_blockName')->setTemplate("FolderName/File.phtml");
       $this->_setActiveMenu('menu/children'); // to set the menu item active
       $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
       $this->renderLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of the config:

```
<action>practiceadmin/adminhtml_index</action>
```

should actually be

```
<action>practiceadmin/index</action>
```

---

This is why the change is necessary.  Consider when given the action of `practiceadmin/adminhtml_index`, the first half is translated into `Practice_Test_Adminhtml` and the second half is translated into `Adminhtml_IndexController` then the two parts are joined together.  The resulting class name has `Adminhtml` in it twice.

Comment: hi clockworkgeek, my afficher.phtml file is not showing. it is showing empty page with menu items

Comment: Your layout says `template="test/afficher.phtml"` but the created file is `Practice/test/afficher.phtml`.  Change either one of those to match the other.